# Обработка нажатия bluetooth мыши

Tags: android-sdk, android

Добрый день!
Есть задача, но пока не получается найти ее решение (гугление до добра не довело). В общем, задача следующая: нужно определить, подключена ли bluetooth мышь, и обработать левый клик мыши по экрану. Возможно ли вообще это сделать нативными средствами android sdk?

Comment: Клик мыши по экрану == клик пальцем. Ваше приложение не получит каких-то особых ивентов. А определить блютус мышь, думаю, можно через встроенные методы работы с Bluetooth. Как это сделать конкретно - не знаю, такой надобности никогда не возникало, но думаю, если получить список подключенных устройств, то определить, какое из них мышь, не трудно...

Comment: Может, кому понадобится определение запейринных девайсов: 
 
    BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    Set<BluetoothDevice> pairedDevices = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();

Но вот как определить тип  bluetooth мыши, еще пока не найдено решение.

Answer (score 1):

Может кому поможет, я решил это простым способом: Суть проста определяем что тип нажатия от мыши нажата левая кнопка мыши.

```
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
    {
        if (event.getPointerCount() == 1)
            if (event.getToolType(0) == MotionEvent.TOOL_TYPE_MOUSE && event.getButtonState() == MotionEvent.BUTTON_PRIMARY)
                startButtonAction();
        return true;
    }
```